# confusion over initialisation in swift

Tags: ios, swift, initialization, subclass, superclass

According to "Swift programming language 2.1", if a subclass provides default value for all of its properties, then the subclass automatically inherits all its superclass's designated initialisers and convenience initialisers. So for the code below, class `ShoppingListItem` should inherit three initialisers, from its superclass, `RecipeIngredient`, i.e.

```
//1
convenience init() {
    self.init(name: "[unnamed]")
}

//2
convenience init(name: String){
    self.init(name: name, quantity: 1)
}

//3
init(name: String, quantity: Int){
    self.quantity = quantity
    super.init(name: name)
}
```

If I want to create an instance of ShoppingListItem, I would write

```
let ingredientThree = ShoppingListItem(name: "apple", quantity: 10)
```

this would invoke the `init(name: String, quantity: Int){}`, but within this initialiser, there is a call to `super.init(name: name)`, this is where I'm getting stuck. What happen when the initialisation process has reached  `super.init(name: name)`? Does it call `ShoppingListItem`'s superclass's `init(name: String){}` initialiser? Or does it not? What exactly happen here? Could someone please kindly explain it to me? Thanks in advance for any help!

Actual code:

```
class Food {
    var name: String
    init(name: String){
        self.name = name
    }
    convenience init() {
        self.init(name: "[unnamed]")
    }

}

class RecipeIngredient: Food{
    var quantity: Int
    init(name: String, quantity: Int){
        self.quantity = quantity
        super.init(name: name)
    }

    override convenience init(name: String){
        self.init(name: name, quantity: 1)
    }
}

class ShoppingListItem: RecipeIngredient {
    var purchased = false
    var description: String {
        var output = "\(quantity) X \(name)"
        output += purchased ? " ✔" : " ✘"
        return output
    }
}
```

Graph from Swift programming language 2.1
[image]

Comment: Sometimes when I see example code from Apple docs I want to travel to Cupertino and slap their authors faces: ShoppingListItem is not an ingredient — it has an ingredient. It should be modeled as a composition, not inheritance. And an ingredient has a food: composition again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put your code into a playground and added some prints. Here is what happens:

- RecipeIngredient.init(String, Int)
- Food.init

Incidentally, you asked if it will call ShoppingListItem's superclass's init(name: String){} initializer.

The answer is no. Your used

```
let ingredientThree = RecipeIngredient(name: "apple", quantity: 10)
```

This has nothing to do with ShoppingListItem.

Generally, if you have class inheritance Class1 <- Class2 <- Class3. And then you instantiate Class2, then Class 3 never comes into play.

```
class Food {
    var name: String
    init(name: String){
        print("Food.init")
        self.name = name
    }
    convenience init() {
        self.init(name: "[unnamed]")
    }

}

class RecipeIngredient: Food{
    var quantity: Int
    init(name: String, quantity: Int){
        print("RecipeIngredient.init(String, Int)")
        self.quantity = quantity
        super.init(name: name)
    }

    override convenience init(name: String){
        self.init(name: name, quantity: 1)
    }
}

class ShoppingListItem: RecipeIngredient {
    var purchased = false
    var description: String {
        var output = "\(quantity) X \(name)"
        output += purchased ? " ✔" : " ✘"
        return output
    }
}
let ingredientThree = RecipeIngredient(name: "apple", quantity: 10)
```

Comment: sorry, what I actually meant is let ingredientThree = ShoppingListItem(name: "apple", quantity: 10), not let ingredientThree = RecipeIngredient(name: "apple", quantity: 10). Could you please refit the answer to this adjustment? Your help will be greatly appreciated!! God bless  you!!

Comment: I assume you can drop the code into a Playground and make the change. You will see what gets called.  There's really no magic in how this works. It's the same as Java, PHP, C++ etc.